# Where to initialise Dalli::Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

I've just started using the Dalli gem for memory caching.

I'm just wondering do I need to create an instance of Dalli::Client in every request if I want to grab some data from the cache or can I declare a singleton which I can reuse?

Answer (score 2):

In your `config/environments/production.rb`:

> config.cache_store = :dalli_store 
>  config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
>   'cache-1.example.com',   { :namespace => NAME_OF_RAILS_APP,
>   :expires_in => 1.day, :compress => true }